# Treeview or Listview master detail ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm tryng to build a ASP.NET aplicacion. How can I select a node and edit the record dataset? Master detail of 4 tables in mysql. Is the code below correct or is there another way to do everything?

[image]
[image: database]

```
 {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBMANUTEN"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnString))

    {
        string SSQLLocalMaq = "Select * from a1_locaismaq";
        string SSQLLocalPiso = "Select * from a2_maquinas";
        string SSQLNomeEqp = "Select * from a3_ponto_lub";
        string SFullSQL = SSQLLocalMaq + ";" + SSQLLocalPiso + ";" + SSQLNomeEqp;

        DataSet dsFullData = new DataSet();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(SFullSQL, Conn);
        da.Fill(dsFullData);
        dsFullData.Tables[0].TableName = "a1_locaismaq";
        dsFullData.Tables[1].TableName = "a2_maquinas";
        dsFullData.Tables[2].TableName = "a3_ponto_lub";

        DataRelation LocalMaq_LocalPiso = new DataRelation("DeptSub", dsFullData.Tables["a1_locaismaq"].Columns["localmaq_inc"], dsFullData.Tables["a2_maquinas"].Columns["localmaq_inc"]);
        dsFullData.Relations.Add(LocalMaq_LocalPiso);

        DataRelation LocalPiso_NomeEqp = new DataRelation("SubTech", dsFullData.Tables["a2_maquinas"].Columns["maquinas_ninc"], dsFullData.Tables["a3_ponto_lub"].Columns["maquinas_ninc"]);
        dsFullData.Relations.Add(LocalPiso_NomeEqp);

        foreach (DataRow oLocalMaq in dsFullData.Tables["a1_locaismaq"].Rows)
        {


            foreach (DataRow oLocalPiso in oLocalMaq.GetChildRows("DeptSub"))
            {



                foreach (DataRow oNomeEqp in oLocalPiso.GetChildRows("SubTech"))
                {
                  TextBox1.Text = oNomeEqp["ponto_designa"].ToString();
            }
        }



        }


    }
}
```